# How does an increase in climb rate affect climb gradient?

Tags: aircraft-performance, climb

I'm learning to take (and pass I hope ;)) my PPL exam and I've just found one question, that I'm not 100% sure about.
How is climb gradient going to change (for small angles) while rate of climb increases 2 times? (TAS = constant)

a) stay the same
b) increase 2 times
c) increase 4 times
d) decrease 2 times

Can I calculate climb gradient as (rate of climb/TAS)? If yes, the correct answer is B. 
Guys, could you please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

For small angles, climb gradient can indeed be approximated using ROC/TAS. Easiest if you draw a sketch for things like this!